# NetSuite Toolkit get tax schedules

Tags: php, netsuite

I am using [NetSuite Toolkit](https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php) to connect and receive information from NetSuite SOAP services.

Everything seems to be working, but I can not find any way to receive Tax Schedules list.

Usually I would use similar code to this:

```
$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = new TaxScheduleSearch();

$service = new NetSuiteService($config);
$service->search($request);
```

but there is no such class as `TaxScheduleSearch` in NetSuite Toolkit, although there is plenty of references to `public \NetSuite\Classes\RecordRef $taxSchedule;` in code...

Is there any way to receive it or Tax Items/Tax Codes?

Answer (score 0):

Not everything in NetSuite is supported via web services and it appears at a glance that this is the case for tax schedules. When in doubt, the official web services schema browser is pretty much the authoritative source of whether or not something is supported.

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/schema/record/account.html

For things like this, you're probably going to need to store the information you need locally, whether in a PHP class or a DB table, and make sure that data is kept up to date if/when it changes.